# Amend description of menu location in customizer wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Amend description of menu locations in customizer? I just want to add note that I have limited menu depth. Not really sure how to do it.

I refer to this description under 'Menu Locations'

> Your theme supports 2 menus. Select which menu appears in each
>   location. You can also place menus in widget areas with the “Custom
>   Menu” widget.

or to add description for Menu panel.

I tried like this

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'nav_menus', array(
'description' => esc_html__( 'new description', 'theme_name' ),
) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is it not sure if its OK to post [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273123/amend-description-of-menu-location-in-customizer-wordpress/273187) to it. Answer by [Weston Ruter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/8521/weston-ruter), thanks!

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function( $wp_customize ) {
    $section = $wp_customize->get_section( 'menu_locations' );
    $section->description .= "<p>Custom HTML added.</p>";
}, 12 );
```

for more informations check out the link above.